# Configure domain name for lambda functions in AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, amazon-route53

I have a react app with a graphql api. I've managed to get a custom domain working with my react app via cloudfront as follows. But I've been trying to do a similar thing for the functions/graphql lambda with no success.

Is there a way of getting a hostedzoneid and dnsname for my lamda functions too? And setting these in my AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup configuration?

BTW: I'm aware of serverless-domain-manager and I'm not keen on using it, I prefer to configure via AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup

```yaml
service: shopify-aws-poc
provider:
  name: aws
  profile: serverless-shop-poc
  region: us-east-1
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  environment:
    SHOPID: ${env:SHOPID}
plugins:
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-s3-sync

custom:
  serverless-offline:
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 4001
    dontPrintOutput: true
  dynamodb:
    stages:
      - dev
    start:
      region: localhost
      host: localhost
      port: 8000
      migrate: true
      seed: true
    seed:
      domain:
        sources:
          - table: 'Shop'
            sources: [local/dynamodb/seed/shop.json]
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true
  bucketName: shop-app-vh8w37h9pjs78rnqfvmhw8
  s3Sync:
    - bucketName: ${self:custom.bucketName}
      localDir: shop-app/build/
functions:
  graphql:
    handler: ./graphql/shop-api/handler.graphqlHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: post
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: get
          cors: true
resources:
  Resources:
    ShopTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        TableName: 'Shop'
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        StreamSpecification:
          StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
    ShopAppBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.bucketName}
        AccessControl: PublicRead
        WebsiteConfiguration:
          IndexDocument: index.html
          ErrorDocument: index.html
    S3AccessPolicy:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties:
        Bucket:
          Ref: ShopAppBucket
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Sid: PublicReadGetObject
              Effect: Allow
              Principal: '*'
              Action:
                - s3:GetObject
              Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucketName}/*
    CloudFrontDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          Origins:
            - DomainName: ${self:custom.bucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com
              Id: ShopApp
              CustomOriginConfig:
                HTTPPort: 80
                HTTPSPort: 443
                OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
          Enabled: true
          Aliases:
            - g8976g7iuyg.mydomain.xyz
          DefaultRootObject: index.html
          CustomErrorResponses:
            - ErrorCode: 404
              ResponseCode: 200
              ResponsePagePath: /index.html
            - ErrorCode: 403
              ResponseCode: 200
              ResponsePagePath: /index.html
          DefaultCacheBehavior:
            AllowedMethods:
                - DELETE
                - GET
                - HEAD
                - OPTIONS
                - PATCH
                - POST
                - PUT
            TargetOriginId: ShopApp
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: false
              Cookies:
                Forward: none
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
          ViewerCertificate:
            AcmCertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:994996037326:certificate/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx
            SslSupportMethod: sni-only
            MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1
            
    DNSRecords: 
      Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
      Properties:
        HostedZoneName: mydomain.xyz.
        RecordSets:
          - Name: g8976g7iuyg.mydomain.xyz
            Type: A
            AliasTarget:
              HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
              DNSName: !GetAtt CloudFrontDistribution.DomainName
```

Comment: Can you point a DNS-Record to a Lambda function? No.
Can you point a DNS-Record to AppSync or whatever invokes your Lambda function? Yes.

Comment: I guess under the hood it's not just a lambda function.  serverless framework builds all this other stuff around it.